# Show woocommerce shop_attributes also in short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to show a copy of the "Extra Informatie" / "Extra Information" Tab inside the short description. I know how to show the tab contents.. But what i do not know is how to extract only the information of this one tab.

Example:

[image: shop_attributes sizes]

Comment: have your tried any thing so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the following code after the short description.

```
<?php 

global $product;

$heading = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_heading', __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ) );

?>

<?php if ( $heading ): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $heading; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $product->list_attributes(); ?>
```